# Nginx: запретить все, кроме index.php

Tags: nginx, php

Есть простой nginx конфиг:

```
server  {
        listen 80;

        root    /var/www/site;
        sendfile off;
        server_name site.loc;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        location /  {
                index index.php;
                #try_files index.php =404;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                root /var/www/site/static;
        }

        location ~ /index\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass php;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Я хотел все запросы переводить на index.php, кроме статических файлов. 
То есть запросы

- site.loc/ => /index.php
- site.loc/config.php => 404
- site.loc/index.html => 404
- site.loc/dir/ => 404
- site.loc/?dd=aa => /index.php?dd=aa
- site.loc/aa.js => /static/aa.js

Подсмотрел в мануале nignx, понял, что все просто:

```
location /  {
                    index index.php;
            }
```

Должно сделать внутренний редирект на `/index\.php$`. 
Но все плохо, выходит `site.loc/ => /index.php` НО `site.loc/config.php => скачивание файла`.

UP.
Пробовал

```
location ^~ ^.*$ {
    deny  all;
    return 404;
}
```

результат `site.loc/ => 404`, ну в мануале объясняться что `location /` имеет приоритет ниже

**Обновление**
вот отрывок дебага для первого случая с таким конифгом

```
location = /          { try_files @index =404; }
location = /index.php { try_files @index =404; }

test location: "/index.php"
2014/11/18 09:12:43 [debug] 20920#0: *1 test location: "/"
2014/11/18 09:12:43 [debug] 20920#0: *1 using configuration "=/"
.....
2014/11/18 09:12:43 [debug] 20920#0: *1 trying to use file: "@index" "/var/www/site@index"
2014/11/18 09:12:43 [debug] 20920#0: *1 trying to use file: "=404" "/var/www/site=404"
2014/11/18 09:12:43 [debug] 20920#0: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/?" a:1, c:1
```

Comment: @duhon, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: ксожелению пока ответа работающего нету

Answer (score 1):

[[@duhon](/users/19768/duhon)](/users/19768/duhon) вам точно нужно 404 отдавать на любые левые запросы?

Можно сделать два точных локэйшна с одинаковым содержанием для index.php, и регэкспом ловить статику, как у вас уже и есть:

```
location = /          { try_files @index =404; }
location = /index.php { try_files @index =404; }
location @index {
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root"index.php";
    ...
}

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    root /var/www/site/static;
}
```

**Обновление**

Посмотрели бы, что там [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) хочет. Допишите `=404`. Я вам для примера написал, не полный конфиг.

```
location = /          { try_files @index  =404; }
```

Comment: invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in try_files @index;

Comment: Посмотрели бы, что там [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) хочет. Допишите там `=404`. Я вам для примера написал, не полный конфиг.

    location = /          { try_files @index  =404; }

Comment: я сначала пишу, потом разбираюсь :).
После применения такого конфига у меня все так как я как раз и не хотел.

 - site.loc => 404
 - site.loc/index.php => 404
 - site.loc/composer.json => выводит содержание

я так понял try_files @index =404; тут нельзя использовать @index не последним аргументом

Answer (score 0):

В настройках сервера тоже пропишите `index index.php;`. Не знаю лежащей под этим философии, но корень почему-то не обрабатывается catch-all локейшеном.

**Обновление**

Подозреваю, дело в этой строчке

```
try_files $uri =404;
```

$uri будет указывать на config.php. Попробуйте сделать `try_files index.php`

**Обновление 2**

1. ПробОвал
2. > ведь в location уже прописано что совпадет /index.php$ только индексный файл, остальные идут лесом

И что? На index.php его перенаправил catch-all, uri при этом остался любым.

Comment: Если дополнительно добавить index index.php в секцию server, то ничего не меняется. А конкретно site.loc/ => /index.php, но site.loc/config.php => скачивание файла.

Comment: это я уже тоже побывал, но даже по логике это тупо, ведь в location уже прописано что совпадет `/index\.php$` только индексный файл, остальные идут лесом, и поэтому try_files $uri =404; дефакто равно try_files /index.php