# Настроить nginx только для обработки index.php и отдачи файлов css,js..(строго перечичленных). Остальное запретить

Tags: nginx, php-nginx

Стоит задача сконфигурировать nginx следующим образом:

1.Запретить всё, что не разрешено.

2.Разрешать исполнение файла index.php в корневой папке. (Естественно правило для обработчика php-fpm)

3.Разрешить выдачу файлов css,js,png(только указанные расширения.)
Запросы на доступ к файлам с другими расширениями и без -
отбрасывать или 404.

Comment: Блин я знаю как на Apache сделать=)

Comment: . htaccess файл ещё никто не отменял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл **.htaccess** вставить такое:

```
Order deny,allow
<FilesMatch "\.(png|css|js)$">
    Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
<Files index.php>
    Allow from All
</Files>
Deny from all
```

Comment: ну или в файл конфига... по усмотрению

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/371559/nginx-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-index-php?rq=1

Comment: вопрос о программе nginx. при чём тут эксклюзивный apache-вский «костыль» htaccess?

Comment: Ребят, вы читать не умеете ?) Nginx, при чём тут htaccess ваш Апачовский 